# How to add security rules to Firestore without Authentication?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm working on a project and  I'm using the device with a gsm module called sim800. Sim 800 is able to get and post requests. But Firebase SDK can not be installed on the device, so I can not do authentication. The device will access the Firestore database with get and post requests and read and write datas. Since the module cannot be Authentication, can I use a token I generated when reuesting?

If this is possible, how should I write the firestore security rules?

Comment: There is actually a REST API for Firebase Authentication: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth. You could use that to mint a normal Firebase Authentication token, and then pass that to Cloud Firestore calls.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported to pass any sort of per-request tokens for use with security rules.  This wouldn't actually be secure, as someone would be able to simply break down the device and extract the token.

The best you can do without Firebase Auth is require that, for new document creations, there is a field in that new document that contains the shared "password" that's agreed upon between the client code and security rule.  But again, this is not really all that secure.

You could also look into finding a way to transmit a pre-authenticated custom Firebase Auth token to the device, and pass that along using the REST API in order to authenticate the access.